# error MSB4057: The target "_WPPCopyWebApplication" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm using my trusty build script from VS2010 in VS2013 but I'm just getting the error:

> error MSB4057: The target "_WPPCopyWebApplication" does not exist in the project

I've tried everything mentioned in the similar questions but nothing seems to fix it.

Here's the start of my build script:

```
<Project  DefaultTargets="AfterBuild" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
        <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
    <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Comment: Check out the [markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) some time. Your code was hidden because it was not formatted.